# How to scale % change based features so that they are viewed "similarly" by the model

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, time-series

I have some features that are zero-centered values and supposed to represent change between a current value and previous value. Generally speaking i believe there should be some symmetry between these values. Ie. there should be roughly the same amount of positive values as negative values and roughly these values should operate on the same scale.

When i try to scale my samples using MaxAbsScaler, i notice that my negative values for this feature get almost completely drowned out by the positive values. And i don't really have any reason to believe my positive values should be that much larger than my negative values.

So what i've noticed is that fundamentally, the magnitude of percentage change values are not symmetrical in scale. For example if i have a value that goes from 50 to 200, that would result in a 300.0% change. If i have a value that goes from 200 to 50 that would result in a -75.0% change. I get there is a reason for this, but in terms of my feature, i don't see a reason why a change of 50 to 100 should be 3x+ more "important" than the same change in value but the opposite direction.

Given this information, i do not believe there would be any reason to want my model to treat a change of 200-50 as a "lesser" change than a change of 50-200. Since i am trying to represent the change of a value over time, i want to abstract this pattern so that my model can "visualize" the change of a value over time that same way a person would.

Right now i am solving this by using this formula

```
if curr > prev:
    return curr / prev - 1
else:
    return (prev / curr - 1) * -1
```

And this does seem to treat changes in value, similarly regardless of the direction. Ie from the example of above 50>200 = 300, 200>50 = -300. Is there a reason why i shouldn't be doing this? Does this accomplish my goal? Has anyone ran into similar dilemmas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a discussion question and it's difficult to know the right answer to it without knowing the physical relevance of your feature. You are calculating a percentage change, and a percent change is dependent on the original value. I am not a big fan of a custom formula only to make percent change symmetric since it adds a layer of complexity when it is unnecessary in my opinion.

If you want change to be symmetric, you can try direct difference or factor change. There's nothing to suggest that difference or factor change are less correct than percent change. So, depending on the physical relevance of your feature, each of the following symmetric measures would be correct ways to measure change -

1. Difference change -> 50 to 200 yields `150`, 200 to 50 yields `-150`
2. Factor change with logarithm -> 50 to 200 yields `log(4)`, 200 to 50 yields `log(1/4) = -log(4)`

Comment: My problem is that i need my methodology to translate across scale. Ie. 5, 10, 15 results in the same set of features as 50, 100, 150

Comment: Wouldn't the factor change accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm i'll have to give that one a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble because you haven't brought the abstract questions into your paradigm.

```
"... my model can "visualize" ... same way a person would."
```

In this paradigm, you need a metric for "same way".  There *is* no such empirical standard.  You've dropped both of the simple standards -- relative error and absolute error -- and you posit some inherently "normal" standard that doesn't exist.

Yes, we run into these dilemmas: choosing a success metric.  You've chosen a classic example from "How To Lie With Statistics"; depending on the choice of starting and finishing proportions and the error metric, you can "prove" all sorts of things.

This brings us to your central question:

```
Does this accomplish my goal?
```

We don't know.  First of all, you haven't given us your actual goal.  Rather, you've given us an indefinite description and a single example of two data points.  Second, you're asking the wrong entity.  Make your changes, run the model on your data set, and examine the properties of the resulting predictions.  Do those properties satisfy your desired end result?

For instance, given your posted data points, (200, 50) and (50, 200), how would other examples fit in, such as (1, 4), (1000, 10), etc.?  If you're simply training on the proportion of change over the *full* range of values involved in that transaction, your proposal is just what you need: use the higher value as the basis.  Since you didn't post any representative data, we have no idea what sort of distribution you have.

Comment: My goal is to create a set of features from a vector that is scale-independent, and if you graph out the values, a change of a magnitude X is weighted equally regardless of direction.